# get string from alertdialog android studio

Tags: android, string, android-alertdialog, gettext

Hello I need to get an string from an alertdialog, this is the code

```
public class alertDialog extends Activity {
     public String result;

    public String show(Context cont) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(cont);
        b.setTitle("Please enter a file name");
        final EditText input = new EditText(cont);
        b.setView(input);
        b.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                result = input.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        b.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
        b.show();
        return result;
    }

    public String resultado (){
        return result;
    }
}
```

But when I call that class

```
            String data;
            alertDialog dialog= new alertDialog();
            data=dialog.show(this);
```

it return a null object. What Im doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: Variable `result` becomes non-null only after user enters text and clicks OK button, not when dialog is shown. That is why result is null.

Comment: But if after display the AlertDialog and the user click on OK button. I use the method resultado() but it return a null object, too.

Comment: Post the code how you call resultado()

Comment: String data;
String second_try;
alertDialog dialog= new alertDialog();
data=dialog.show(this);
second_try=dialog.resultado();

And second_try keep being null

Comment: `second_try` is null for the same reason: your code does not wait till the user clicks OK button. `dialog.resultado()` is called immediately after the dialog is shown.

Comment: You should handle result in `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)`, you cannot obtain it immediately after dialog is shown.